# Looping until Background Thread Completes

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have created a Form for long-running Tasks, it's purpose is to loop a Progress Bar until the Thread completes. I display this Form as a Dialog so that my main application is Waiting until this Form returns.

Unfortunately, my RunWorkerCompleted is being called before the Thread actually finishes its task.

What is an effective method of Waiting for a Thread to Finish, WITHOUT Joining?

```
public partial class FormProcessing : Form
{
    public ThreadStart StartTaskFunc { get; set; }

    public FormProcessing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
        bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        Shown += (s, e) =>
        {
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        };
    }

    void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() => StartTaskFunc());
        thread.Start();
        int i = 0;
        while (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            if (i == 26)
                i = 0;
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(i);
            Task.Delay(200).Wait();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using a marquee progress bar, rather than a regular progress bar, since you're not actually updating the progress bar with any meaningful progress value.

Comment: I good suggestion, however I still need to hold the form open until the Thread completes, any suggestions? Or are you saying to run the task on the Form's Thread, and just display a Marquee?

Comment: You should just be doing your work right in the `DoWork` handler, not creating another thread to do it.  As it is you're creating a new thread that creates a new thread and then waits for it to finish.  Just don't create the second thread.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: Worked Perfect, thanks! I don't know why I was creating another Thread! :-\

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another "Thread" in "bgWorker_DoWork" method.

If you create another thread, the "bgWorker_DoWork" is completed as soon as the new thread is created.